# Edit the background colour of the "Edit" view in moreNavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

```
class mainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        tabBarController?.delegate = self

        self.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 25.0/255.0, green: 25.0/255.0, blue: 25.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        let view = self.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view as UITableView

        for cell in view.visibleCells(){
            let tableCell = cell as UITableViewCell
            tableCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 25.0/255.0, green: 25.0/255.0, blue: 25.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            tableCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
    }

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, willBeginCustomizingViewControllers viewControllers: [AnyObject]) {

        let editView = tabBarController.view.subviews[1] as UIView
        editView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Here is my current code. I got the code that's in the 'willBeginCustomizingViewControllers' from an old website (around 4-5 years old) and it worked then apparently but it's not doing anything now. I want to change the background of the "Edit" modal view within the moreNavigationController to the same colour as i have set to the table cells in the viewWillAppear. I've put red for now just to test. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research, but i cant seem to find anything. I'm not sure its even possible.

There is one more option, but its not so easy. You can call your fifth tab 'more',  and place a collection view inside it to access all of the other tabs (just copy apple's 'more' tab, but just start from scratch on a new view controller.).

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. This only changed the colour of the tab bar icons and text.

Comment: I think you're confused as to what the problem is. I'm trying to set the colour for the background for when the user presses Edit. This is a new view that shows up modally. I have managed to set the colours for the tab bar and background under the more tab (before pressing Edit).

Comment: really do appreciate your effort but again nope :( it's not the navigation bar that's the problem, it's the actual view background. If you open the stock Music app and press on more and then edit, I'm trying to change that white background to a different colour